# Sencha touch: Using XTemplate

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a store with which i am populating a list. The store is as follows:

```
Ext.define('EventReminder.store.Upcoming', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.SQL'],
config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'Upcoming',
    model: 'EventReminder.model.Event',
    proxy: {
        type: 'sql',
        database: 'EventReminder',
        table: 'NewEvents'
    },
    sorters: [{property: 'date', direction: 'ASC'}]}
});
```

The list is as follows:

```
{
xtype: 'list',
flex: 1,
autoDestroy: false,
itemId: 'upcomingEventList',
onItemDisclosure: true,
store: 'Upcoming',
cls: 'event-list',
scrollable: true,
}
```

I have created an XTemplate for this list as follows:

```
var xtpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '   <tpl if="priority == \'high\'">',
        '       <div class = "color-event-high">',
        '          <div class="event-category">{category}</div>',
        '          <div class="event-date">On: {date} at: {eventTime}</div>',
        '          <div>Alert at : {alertTime}</div>',
        '          <div class="event-people">People: {people}</div>',
        '           <div class="event-message">{message}</div>',
        '          <div class="event-priority">{priority}</div>',
        '          <div class="event-activities">{activities}</div>',
        '      </div>',
        '   </tpl>',
        '</tpl>'
);
```

Here i want to give a styling based on the priority value of the list item. I have set the tpl of the list as follows in the view's initialize function as follows:

```
this.down("#upcomingEventList").setItemTpl(xtpl);
```

I Normally specify ItemTpl for a list directly in its config and don't know much about using XTemplates. So when i use the above Xtemplate the list doesn't show the items. I've checked the documentation and but could'nt understand how these XTemplates work. I've seen other answers for similar questions but did'nt help much.

Is this the correct way to write an XTemplate for a List, if we want some conditional styling based on the list items?

Comment: Your template looks correct to me... Did you try to put the XTemplate directly in the config with `itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('your_template')`

Comment: @qmat You should never instantiate an object within the config. Just do `itemTpl: 'your_template'` instead.

Comment: My guess is that the list is properly build, but not showing up because of the `flex: 1`. Try to give it a `height` or a `fullscreen: true` and look in devtools if there is any html rendered for the list.

Comment: Actually the list is getting rendered if i don't use an XTemplate and simply use the itemTpl config @Tarabass so i think the `flex:1` should not be any problem

Comment: Ok so i found out that the value that i am checking in the if condition is slightly different than what it is obtaining from the store. I'm sorry for posting the question without a proper investigation. Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out yourself. This is exactly why I avoid templates, and use objects/listitems where I can.